# How to set up a model where some properties are from legacy sources

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the best practice method for establishing an Entity Framework data model when some of the properties for the data model are from various legacy sources?

For example:

Suppose you're creating a new Employee Management Portal, and so we want an Employee entity, with things like FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, etc. being new properties stored in the portal's database (which we don't mind if EF creates on first run)

However, say some other properties of the Employee come from outside legacy sources, e.g.:

- suppose current amount of Vacation time comes from a different database that already exists and we do not have permission to have EF monkey with (although we are allowed to have EF update the values)
- Suppose current Health Plan information comes from a web service for which we do not have write access at all.

**Is there a way to set up Entity Framework such that we can grab an Employee entity and have it populated with these externally-sourced properties?**

Sub-question: **is there a way to have EF interface with a different database and table for a specific property? (e.g. the vacation time property?)**

Comment: It would be worth looking at AutoMapper - https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper , it is really good for DTO's. For the second question, could you not just have another model with a different connection string?

Comment: Let me make sure I'm understanding: are you saying I should have the stuff that gets stored in the local DB (firstname, lastname, etc.) as EF entity objects, then grab the externally sourced objects wherever I can get them, and then combine them into a third object (say viewmodel) with AutoMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tool has its scope. This is beyond the scope of EF. EF is totally monogamous when it comes to data stores. One context, one store. We could invent a few creative tricks to circumvent this restriction, but the result would be less than the sum of the parts.

For instance, `ObjectContext` (accessible through `DbContext`) has an [`ObjectMaterialized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

> Occurs when a new entity object is created from data in the data source as part of a query or load operation.

You *could* use this event to capture the materialization of `Employee` object. Then, when a new object is created, call the other data sources to fill the remaining properties. This would be one database call (through another EF context, because it's a different database) and a web service call *per object*. Performance goes down the drain.

Likewise, you *could* override `SaveChanges` and save "alien" properties to other stores. But again, this would knock down performance. (Although here you could process a complete set of employees at once).

This is typically something you do in a service that has access to various data sources and orchestrates their operations. I.e. grab the `Employee` objects from the portal database, all items you need at once, and then access the other sources to populate other properties. You may want to add these properties to `Employee` as unmapped properties, or use some sort of "canonic" employee class that is populated from the separate data sources.

Comment: OK so it sounds like I need a layer inbetween EF and the app to assemble the Employee object, meaning any subsequent developers will have to avoid using EF directly and instead use the layer (Repository pattern probably), which will have Get() method which will, say: 1) get Employee from EF, 2) grab the Vacation time from other DB and populate it; and 3) grab Health Plan info from web service. That makes sense.

I suppose the only wrinkle that this creates is the issue where the Employee gets saved OK but something goes awry when writing one of the "alien" properties. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you have a table that can store all of the data you are wanting to store, including the one you get from other sources such as vacation time and health plan information.

If you already do, then create a [POCO](http://www.vkinfotek.com/poco/poco-class-entity-framework.html) (plain-old" CLR objects) class in your business logic layer that includes property names that match with your EF entity object as shown below:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public int VacationTime { get; set; }
        public string HealthPlanName { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your code where you get the data from these other sources you will need to create a new Employee object, assign the values you got from the other sources and persist it with EF as shown below:

```
var newEmployee = new Employee {
            FirstName = "somename",
            LastName = "somelastname",
            JobTitle = "somejobtitle",
            VacationTime = someservice.VacationTime,
            HealthPlanName = someotherservice.HealthPlanName
           };

        db.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Of course this is very simplistic but hopefully it gives you an idea on how to accomplish what you need. The fact that some of the data you need to add to your Employee entity is coming from different sources should not change the way you use EF to persist it.